# How to handle large Images?

Tags: c#, python, c++, google-maps

I want to create my own Google Map like [this:](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html)

**My problem is that I can't load and edit my large images.**

My Images:

- PNG / JPG
- 700 MiB
- 300000px x 300000px

My attempts:

- ImageMagick
- .NET C# / BitmapImages ...
- C++ / OpenCV
- general image classes in Java and Python

**With which language / library I can edit these big images.**

Comment: Try turning the large image into many smaller images and puzzle them together as if they were one large image.

Comment: The thing is, you have multiple images that (300,000 x 300,000) are about ~167GB large (considering 4bits per component, 16bits per pixel). Imagine having to store this in ram! As @JasonHeddle said, you need to fragment the images into smaller ones. After all, there's no point in trying to display this many pixels on a 1080p screen ;)

Comment: Right idea... but @PhilippeParé it does say "*700MB*" and "*PNG/JPG*" which are roughly speaking lossless and lossy kinds of image compression, so maybe they are not actually as big as 167GB.

Comment: So @CodeEX, where did you *get* these 300,000 x 300,000 pixel images? How where they created?

Comment: @uhoh Hello uhoh, I generate the images from [Arma 3 Topography](http://killzonekid.com/arma-scripting-tutorials-how-to-export-topography/) Maps. And I want create own Google Maps [Google Maps API](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html)

Answer (score 6):

I help maintain [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/), an image processing library designed to work with very large images. It's free and works on Linux, Mac and Windows. You can use it from the command-line, [C#](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips), [C/C++](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/), [Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-vips) and others.

You can make your google maps tiles from the command-line like this:

```
vips dzsave hugefile.tif myoutputdir --layout google
```

Or from Python (for example) like this:

```
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("somehugefile.tif", access="sequential")
image.dzsave("filename/of/pyramid", layout="google")
```

And it'll scan your huge tiff image and generate all the tiles. It's fast, it needs little memory and it'll work on images of any size. I regularly make 200,000 x 200,000 deepzoom images from microscope slides using my small laptop.

There's a [chapter in the libvips docs introducing `dzsave` and explaining how to use it](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but I need a little more space than a comment can give.

Take a look at the [large image support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel) section on the  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or the [discussion board](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735699/3904031) mentions the [VIPS package](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) which might be helpful.

You might also consider posting in [photography stackexchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), or even [blender stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions) - for example I saw [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16261/5334) which mentions writing individual [image tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering) - also [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_data_server), although that question is about rendering. Blender is not specifically for image processing and editing, but it's pretty amazing and flexible and has a very active and supportive community. You can use python within Blender as well.

You could also think of asking in [gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=large+images).

When you post in the other stackexchanges, take a look around first and make sure you write your question so that it does not look too off-topic for that site.

Good luck - it seems tiling is everywhere!